# React Native - Shadows over view StyleSheet

Tags: styles, react-native

Z-Index in React Native is based on the [order of rendering](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/698). Just for example, say I have a header to a ListView list item.

So assume the bare `ListItem`:

```
<View>
  <View>Header</View>
  <View>BodyContent</View>
</View>
```

Essentially, I just want the header to have a slight **shadow above the body** content.

However since Z-index is rendered on the base of ordering, the header is under the body content (and so is the shadow).

I attempted to add a shadow with a slightly large offset so that the shadow appears only at the bottom. It looks fine until the image appears over it.

EDIT:

I would like the shadow to come from the header going slightly over the body. Similar to a navigation bar and it's content.

Comment: Try applying an `inset` shadow on the header instead.

Comment: I might be overlooking, but I can only set a shadow offset https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style

Comment: So you’re not actually using CSS?

Comment: Removed tag - sorry not all CSS attributes are implemented in react-native yet.

Comment: Oh, I see… then I can’t help you, but could you please [edit] your question to clarify how exactly the shadow should look like? Should it go in the direction of the body or in the direction of the header? I’m still confused about this.